# Can't use system("start ...") with path arguments that contains spaces

Tags: c++, windows, command-line, path

I'm trying to other executables from my C++ program with an argument of a required path for my other executable to use. I tried

```
system("start \"Title\" \"C:\\Path\\To Exe\\With\\Spaces\\Program.exe\" \"C:\\Argument\\Of\\Another\\Path\\Also With\\Spaces\"");
```

but I get an error saying `'C:\Path\To' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` I believe this is caused because I have 2 arguments that resides between double quotes for the `start` command. When I give a path without spaces and without quotes for my argument it works.

However since both path to my executable and my argument which is another path for my program to use may contain spaces, I believe I have to cover them with quotes. How can I run this kind of a command from my C++ program?

Comment: Can you try it with just one set of (escaped) quotes enclosing the entire command-line?

Comment: Enclosing the entire command with a single pair of quotes makes it a single path and tries to execute `C:\Path\To Exe\With\Spaces\Program.exe C:\Argument\Of\Another\Path\Also With\Spaces`

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround by using

`system("cmd /c (\"Path\" -flag -param=\"value\" \"OtherPath\")");`

as stated here: https://superuser.com/questions/1602807/how-to-pass-a-second-parameter-with-quotes-with-cmd-exe-k